# Updating product page using a Shopify app

Tags: node.js, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

Im trying to write a shopify app that updates the product page (changes the way the units appear) if a certain tag is present.

I went over the QR code app tutorial but I wonder if anyone can direct me to how to make updates to the product page html using my app? Also I assume you need an app to do that but is it possible to make such a change by just theme customization?

I'm looking for a simple example app that makes a simple modification to the product page.

Thank you